# Better formula for multiple sumproducts

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have the following data in range "A1:E3"

```
1   2   12  25  30
3   13  23  28  31
5   14  17  18  35
```

I need to find out how many numbers falls in the range of 1 to 10 in each row. Eg. In Row 1, there are 2 numbers in the range of 1 to 10, in Row 2, there is only 1 and in Row 3, there is 1 so the total is 2+1+1=4. Similarly, I need to find how many numbers falls in the range of 11 to 20, 21 to 30 and 31 to 40 for each row. I wrote a sumproduct formula and added it twice by changing the range.

```
1   to  10  4
11  to  20  5
21  to  30  4
31  to  40  2
```

I have the above date in Range G1:J4 where column J has the below formula which is pulled down 2 more rows.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$1:E$1>=G1)*(A$1:E$1<=I1))+SUMPRODUCT((A$2:E$2>=G1)*(A$2:E$2<=I1))+SUMPRODUCT((A$3:E$3>=G1)*(A$3:E$3<=I1))
```

When my rows increases, the formula grows bigger and bigger. Can anyone suggest a better formula for this?

Thanks

Comment: You don't really need a separate SUMPRODUCT function for each row, this will work  `=SUMPRODUCT((A$1:E$3>=G1)*(A$1:E$3<=I1))`, and can be expanded for any number of rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frequency formula was built specifically for this type of problem.  In my worksheet I highlighted the range "C8:C11" and I array entered this formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=FREQUENCY(A1:E3,B8:B11)
```

[image]

Comment: i got the first answer correct but when i pull down, the ranges also change and dont get the correct result. In your solution, I see same formula being used for all four cells below...

Comment: You don't drag down the range.  As stated, I highligted the range "C8:C11" and I then entered the formula.  In other words you have to highlight al ofl the cells of where your formula is going to be placed before array entering the formula.

Comment: oh! i misundersood. today i learnt something new. thanks buddy... god bless!

Comment: i am struggling to find solution for a similar question and would post here shortly if I am unsuccessful. Kindly have a look at it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

[image: proof of concept]

set up your criteria table in G2:I5 lets say with your data in A1:E3

## OPTION 1 COUNTIF

in J2 use the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:E3,"<="&I2)
```

in J3 and copy down use:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$E$3,"<="&I3)-SUM($J$2:J2)
```

alternatively if you know J1 will be blank in your case you can use the following in J2 and just copy down as needed

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$E$3,"<="&I2)-SUM($J$1:J1)
```

Caveat:  Because I did not do a lower boundary check, all values less than 1, ie 0, -3, 0.34 will all get counted in the 1-10 range.  This option was done on the assumption you were looking for integers greater than 0.

## OPTION II COUNTIFS

use COUNTIFS so set your boundaries for each test range

In J2 use the following and copy down:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$E$3,">="&$G2,$A$1:$E$3,"<="&$I2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to find how numbers are distributed in bins of 10 `(0~10,11~20,..)`. It is better to dedicate the header row to form bin limits and then use a formula that can be dragged to right and downwards - this `SUMPRODUCT` formula does the function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A3:$D3>=1*E$1)*($A3:$D3<=E$2))*1)
```

This is the result achieved.

[image]

The area between the bins and data gives the distribution of numbers.